# Replace with NA except last row given ID with R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7),dna=c(232,424,5345,45345,45,345,4543,345345,4545))
y <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7),year=c(2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2000,2001,2002))
x <- transform(x, rec = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
y <- transform(y, rec = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))

df <- merge(x, y, c("id", "rec"))
df
```

I would like to replace column values of `dna` with `NA` except the last row given `id` and `rec`. How can I do this efficiently? Ideal would be solution in base R. Thanks!

The desired output:

```
   id rec   dna year
1  1   1     NA 2001
2  1   2     NA 2002
3  1   3   5345 2003
4  2   1     NA 2005
5  2   2     45 2006
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$dna <- with(df, ave(dna, df$id, FUN = function(x){
  if ((len <- length(x)) > 1) 
    x[1:(len-1)] <- NA 
  x
}))
df
#   id rec    dna year
# 1  1   1     NA 2001
# 2  1   2     NA 2002
# 3  1   3   5345 2003
# 4  2   1     NA 2005
# 5  2   2     45 2006
# 6  7   1     NA 2000
# 7  7   2     NA 2001
# 8  7   3 345345 2002
```

Comment: although this wouldnt work if there was only one rec for any id

Answer (score 2):

Although you asked base R solution, but here's a `data.table` solution (just in case efficiency matters)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := .N, by = id][rec != indx, dna := NA_real_, by = id]

#    id rec    dna year indx
# 1:  1   1     NA 2001    3
# 2:  1   2     NA 2002    3
# 3:  1   3   5345 2003    3
# 4:  2   1     NA 2005    2
# 5:  2   2     45 2006    2
# 6:  7   1     NA 2000    3
# 7:  7   2     NA 2001    3
# 8:  7   3 345345 2002    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
transform(df, dna = ave(dna, id, FUN = function(x) "is.na<-"(x, -length(x))))

#   id rec    dna year
# 1  1   1     NA 2001
# 2  1   2     NA 2002
# 3  1   3   5345 2003
# 4  2   1     NA 2005
# 5  2   2     45 2006
# 6  7   1     NA 2000
# 7  7   2     NA 2001
# 8  7   3 345345 2002
```

Answer (score 2):

On the `id` column, you could use the `duplicated` function with its `fromLast` argument. We can then wrap that in a vector subset  of the `dna` column and assign our `NA` values to the result.

```
> df$dna[duplicated(df$id, fromLast = TRUE)] <- NA
> df
#   id rec    dna year
# 1  1   1     NA 2001
# 2  1   2     NA 2002
# 3  1   3   5345 2003
# 4  2   1     NA 2005
# 5  2   2     45 2006
# 6  7   1     NA 2000
# 7  7   2     NA 2001
# 8  7   3 345345 2002
```